# Save an entity object from an other entity controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entitymanager

I have a form for an entity "Coupon". In this form, I have a form for an Entity "Annotation". Since I use Entity "Coupon" controller to access the form of Entity "Annotation", I handle the submission of "Annotation" in this controller ("Coupon" controller). But when I handle the submission and try to persist and flush the data, none of it is stored in my Entity "Annotation" table. I think it is because doctrine uses the entitymanager of "Coupon".

I hope I'm clear enough. Can you help me on this ?

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Coupon $coupon)
{
    $modified = new \DateTime('now');
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER', null, 'Vous n\'avez pas les droits nécessaires!');
    // Ici on bloque l'accès au coupon pour les autres utilisateurs
    $coupon->setAccess(0);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($coupon);
    $em->flush($coupon);

    // ensuite on affiche le formulaire coupon et/ou on le traite
    $editForm = $this->createForm('GestCoupons\CouponBundle\Form\CouponType', $coupon);
    if ( $editForm->get('dateAjout') != null ) {
        $editForm->get('dateMaj')->setData($modified->format('d/m/Y H:i'));
    }
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    //on cree le formulaire d'annotation et/ou on le traite
    $annot = new Annotation();
    $annotForm = $this->createForm('GestCoupons\AnnotationBundle\Form\AnnotationType', $annot);
    $annotForm->get('coupon')->setData($coupon->getId());
    $annotForm->get('date')->setData($modified->format('d/m/Y H:i'));
    $annotForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $coupon->setAccess(1);
        $em->persist($coupon);
        $em->flush($coupon);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('coupon_show', array('id' => $coupon->getId()));
    }

    if ($annotForm->isSubmitted() && $annotForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('annotation');
        $em->persist($annot);
        $em->flush($annot);
    }
```

Thanks ahead for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just redirecting before the `Annotation` is saved ? A valid coupon form would mean you hit return `$this->redirectToRoute()` before the `Annotation` is saved. Why are you using different managers btw ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. No, with this code I get an error that says to me "no manager annotation". Thus it uses the statement that annotForm was submitted :).

Comment: It seems to me you're doing manually a lot of steps that could (should) be done automatically. If you have a relation ManyToOne (or OneToOne or whatever) between Coupon and Annotation, then your annotation Form should be a child form of Coupon form and Doctrine would take care of everything for you. Read [this doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html) and you'll understand better what I mean.

Comment: Hi Roubi, 

In fact it works as coded. But Yes indeed I could use relationships. I think I will implement a ManyToOne relationship in order to work more closely to symfony philosophy and architecture. Thank you for your help